# How to solve this multivariable exponential equation?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, functions, logarithms, exponential-function

I searched if this was asked before but couldn't find a solution. I have this equation

> $y^{70} = x + 500 $
>
> $y^{50} = x + 1 $

Is it possible to solve this equation? The only thing I could do is to bring it into this form and then cross-multiply which didn't yield many results.

> $y^{20} = \frac{x+500}{x+1} $

Comment: Subtracting the equations gives $y^{70} - y^{50} = 499,$ which is a [trinomial equation](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22trinomial+equation%22+Lagrange). For a rough idea of the nature of the solutions, you can consider rough hand-sketches of $y = x^{70}$ and $y = x^{50} + 499,$ and observe that by general principles of what the graphs look like there will be two points where the graphs intersect, one for a negative value of $x$ (hence, a negative value of $y$ in your equations) and the other for a positive value of $x$ (hence, a positive value of $y$ in your equations).

Comment: Also, this is an algebraic system of equations, not an exponential system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best I can think of at the moment is

$$
\eqalign{
  & \left\{ \matrix{
  50\ln y = \ln \left( {1 + x} \right) \hfill \cr 
  20\ln y = \ln \left( {{{x + 500} \over {x + 1}}} \right) = \ln \left( {1 + {{499} \over {x + 1}}} \right) \hfill \cr}  \right.  \cr 
  & \ln y = {1 \over {50}}\ln \left( {1 + x} \right) = {1 \over {20}}\ln \left( {1 + {{499} \over {x + 1}}} \right)  \cr 
  & \left( {1 + x} \right)^{\,2/5}  = 1 + {{499} \over {x + 1}}  \cr 
  & \left( {1 + x} \right)^{\,7/5}  = x + 1 + 499  \cr 
  & 1 + x = u^{\,5}   \cr 
  & u^{\,7}  - u^{\,5}  = u^{\,5} \left( {u^{\,2}  - 1} \right) = 499 \cr} 
$$

which clearly has only one solution, and that numerically is easy to solve.

Comment: Thanks. I used this to find u = 2.49085 so x = 95.88217 and y = 1.095556. If I take this one step further and add one more equation which is y^80 = 800+x, how should I approach that?

Comment: then you would have three equations in the two variables $x,y$, which in the general case cannot be simultaneously verified.

Answer (score 1):

Raise the first one to the fifth power to get $$y^{350}=(x+500)^5$$

Raise the second one to the seventh power to get $$ y^{350}=(x+1)^7$$

Thus you have $$(x+500)^5=(x+1)^7$$
This is a seventh degree polynomial to solve.